# C# Calculate total of row

Tags: c#, datagridview

I created a pos payform, but when the same product is detected it automatically detect it and it is incrementing the quantity row but not the final price row. Here is my code :

```
private void Dodadivotabela()
{
    bool Found = false;

    if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Value) == txtBarajKod.Text)
            {
                row.Cells[3].Value =
                Convert.ToString(1 + Convert.ToInt64(row.Cells[3].Value));
                Found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!Found)
    {
        price = float.Parse(txtCena.Text);
        quantity = float.Parse(txtKolicina.Text);
        finalprice = price *  quantity;

        var firstrow = txtBarajKod.Text;
        var secrow = txtNaziv.Text;
        var thirdrow = price;
        var forthrow = quantity;
        var fifthrow = finalprice;

        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(prvred, vtorred, tretred, cetvrtred, pettired);
    }
}
```

And here is my calculation of total row:

```
 public void PresmetajTotal()
 {
     var vkp = 0;
     for (var i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
     {
         vkp += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
         txtTotal.Text = vkp.ToString();
     }
 }
```

The problem is that there are 4 rows in the DGV, and the quantity row gets updated but the row with the final price stays the same.

Comment: When you are setting value of `row.Cells[3]` You should also calculate the finalprice from `txtCena` and `txtKolicina` and set that in `row.Cells[4]`.

Comment: please move this line out of for loop  {  txtTotal.Text = vkp.ToString(); }

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running the calculation when Found is false when you want to run it when "Found" is true

```
If(Found){...}
```

Rather than

```
If(!Found){...}
```